# Add a Date Filter Pentaho Report

Tags: database, filter, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have installed Pentaho community version and started working on it. I just don't have much knowledge on Pentaho yet. I have a problem with a scenario which is like following and if someone could help with it that would be a great help.

I have a table with two columns like "From Date" and "To Date". I need to create a report with the data in this table. But I need to add a date filter to the report. So the records with user input date are in the middle of "From Date" and "To Date" should appear in the report. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add two date parameters in the report.
once you select new report,on right end side you will find data tab,click on that.
at the end you will find parameters tab.
You can search for parameterised report example, you will find many samples.

Comment: That means the user will see two date prompts to enter from date and to date right? Can't I have one single date filter to filter out records with from date and to date in between the user entered date

Comment: you can do that.implement logic on procedure level.
for example : selected date= to_date
from_date = to_date - 7